# how does one pass an Armadillo vec/mat as a ref argument to another method?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I apologise as it might be a daft question but:
I want to use a function to fill my matrix but am struggling to pass it as an argument.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not simply return the matrix you want from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void FillMyMatrix(MyMatrixType& thisIsTheNameOfTheLocalVariableInTheFoo)
{
  // fill your matrix called thisIsTheNameOfTheLocalVariableInTheFoo
  // let's say the MyMatrixType has an Insert(int, int, int) method.
  thisIsTheNameOfTheLocalVariableInTheFoo.Insert(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Yellow, I was sure to have tried this and got an error message back but it does work indeed... Friday afternoon job from me :)